# Velocity for new java projects

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, velocity

It seems velocity for java has been around for quite some time. For someone serious about trying to enforce a separation of their display/view code from their model code. It appears to be quite a simple but powerful alternative.

For new projects would you recommend velocity, or are there newer alternatives?

It appears at least useful for email templating, but would you go the whole hog and use it for an entire web application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a fine templating solution.  I'm working on an app that uses Velocity for both e-mail and HTML pages, and it works great.  I can recommend it wholeheartedly from first-hand experience.

Don't be put off by its age.  I think it's a solid technology that's mature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend one of the mature ones (Velocity or Freemarker).  There aren't really any other notable names in Java templating for good reason.  Both are still solidly supported products.

Oh, and if you are going to use Velocity for your whole webapp (which i also recommend), then be sure to check out the VelocityTools project!